# upload image along with json in ios using multipart/mixed

Tags: ios

I am new to ios webservices ,so i am stuck with a problem for the last 2 to 3 days ,
I have to send a request to server which has multiple parts like image and json ,I tried to use the multipart/form-data to send my request but for some reason the server was not able to get the request ,can anyone help me to solve this problem

The code i am using is

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);

   NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];

 NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];

    [theRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


 NSMutableString *theBody = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    [theBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary]];

     [theBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n"]];

//append The Json string

[theBody appendString:myJsonString];

[theBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", boundary]]; 

//this appends the image

[theBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"; filename=\"photo\""]];

[theBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n"]];

[theBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageData]];

[theBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] ];

[theRequest setHTTPBody:[theBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I felt complex using NSMutableURLRequest directly, Please try using "ASIFormDataRequest", it is easy to use. And they have many other functionalities also, like caching response, canceling a request. The documentation is [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

Answer (score 0):

So, basically what I get that you're facing the problem while sending the image within the `JSON`.

In this case, what you can do first of all you breakdown your image in `NSData` and after that data you need `Base64` encoder scheme, like that:

```
[Base64 encode:(NSData)data]
```

Now, you can store in your required structure, like say if you need to store in dictionary, then you can achieve the same, like that:

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[dict setObject:[Base64 encode:data] forKey:@"imageBytes"]; // I did in single step but if you need you can do two steps...
```

now, just use the `JSON` as you used earlier.

In any concern, let me know. :)

Comment: Hi Mohit Thanks for your help ,but the problem i will face with this is by encoding to base64 it will increase the file size by 33%  .That is the reason i was looking for multipart can you help me with the multipart request

Comment: Hey, I just put a sample at: "http://pastie.org/5452037". Check it out, may be it'll sort-out your problem.

Comment: It is the same code i was using earlier before trying the base64encoding ,and it was not working ...My doubt in this is whether we have to configure something in the server side to accept the multipart request because the server is giving multipart servlet parse error

Comment: Hey, may be you're using J2EE for back end and in this case I don't know much more. But, if you closely inspect the code(for which I provided you the link), you'll find some changes as written by you. At my end, it's working fine.